# React change component inside de main div based on Sidebar link

Tags: reactjs

I`m beginner in React and I want to create page where I include a Navbar and Sidebar and the main to by changed by Sidebar link. How I do that?

exemple:

```
import Sidebar from '../Sidebar';
import Navbar from '../Navbar;
import {Page1,Page2,Page3} from './menu'

export default function UserPage(){
  return(
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Sidebar />
      <div>
        //Here i want to component be loaded based on Navlink
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

**I found the problem!**
If you keep the navbar or sidebar in path="/" don`t use **exact** in the route because when you will go to **"/dashboard"** he will not add them

Answer (score 0):

## Use a Router

For routing in react you can look up `react router` [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

You then define your routes and that will fill your content based on url.

### Example

See how this is like a normal react component, each route will load some specified components. Anything that exists on every page can be put outside of the `Switch` component. You cna see the Nav bar here that will exist on every page.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: i tried but he send me to that component. I want that component to get in my container that have Navbar and Sidebar included not to go to that component